# Sending the ID of a Mui-Datatables row for an edit modal on React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, datatables, material-ui, mui-datatable

I've been lurking Stack Overflow forever, I've always been able to find solutions without asking, but I've come across an issue that I can't solve.

I've got the following code:

```
 const columns = [
    {
        name: "_id",
        label: "Id",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: true,
            display: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "messageId",
        label: "ID",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "messageContent",
        label: "Message",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },

    {
        name: "showFrom",
        label: "showFrom",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "showUntil",
        label: "Show Until",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "colour",
        label: "colour",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Edit",
        options: {
            filter: true,
            sort: false,
            empty: true,
            customBodyRender: () => {
                return (
                    <button onClick={setEditMessage(_id)}>
                        Edit
                    </button>
                );
            }
        }
    },
];
```

This sets the columns for a MUI-Datatables I'm using to display some messages from MongoDB. There's a specific ID these messages have, accessible through the _id column. I would like to then pass on a specific row's ID to an edit modal component, which has the following code:

```
const MessageModal = () => {
    const {
        isLoading,
        isEditing,
        showAlert,
        displayAlert,
        colourOptions,
        handleChange,
        clearValues,
        createMessage,
        editMessage,
        setEditJob, _id,
messageId,
messageContent,
showFrom,
showUntil,
colour,


    } = useAppContext()

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!messageId || !messageContent || || !showFrom || !showUntil) {
            displayAlert()
            return
        }
        if (isEditing) {
            editMessage()
            return
        }
        createMessage()
    }
    const handleMessageInput = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value
        handleChange({name, value})
    }

    // modal consts
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>

            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                Create Message
            </Button>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>

                    <DialogTitle>{isEditing ? 'Edit Message' : 'Create Message'}</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            Please fill up the following fields.
                        </DialogContentText>
                        {showAlert && <Alert/>}

                        <FormRow type="text" labelText='Message ID' name="messageId" value={messageId}
                                 handleChange={handleMessageInput}/>
                       
                        <FormRow type="text" labelText='Message' name="messageContent" value={messageContent}
                                 handleChange={handleMessageInput}/>


                        <FormRow type="date" labelText='Show From' name="showFrom" value={showFrom}
                                 handleChange={handleMessageInput}/>
                        <FormRow type="date" labelText='Show Until' name="showUntil" value={showUntil}
                                 handleChange={handleMessageInput}/>
                        <FormRowSelect name="colour" value={colour} handleChange={handleMessageInput}
                                       list={colourOptions}/>


                    </DialogContent>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                        <Button
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault()
                                clearValues()
                            }}>
                            Clear Message
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={isLoading}>Create Message</Button>
                    </DialogActions>

                </Dialog>
            </form>
        </div>


    )
}
```

This is the SET EDIT MESSAGE action in the reducer:

```
 if(action.type === SET_EDIT_MESSAGE){
    const message = state.messages.find((message)=> message._id === action.payload.id)
    const {_id, messageId, messageContent, showFrom, showUntil, colour } = message
    return {
        ...state,
        isEditing: true,
        editMessageId:  _id,
        messageId,
        messageContent,
        showFrom,
        showUntil,
        colour
    }
}
```

This should be able to grab the ID from the row and load it so that the modal can then know what data to pull and push. Yet it doesn't work and I'm not entirely sure why. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure but it seems that the state you returned in your reducer action isn't correct. Don't you need to return all the messages within the state?

Comment: Something like { ...state, messages: [ ...state.messages, theEditedMessage] }

Comment: I've tried, but then I get the error in the console saying that message is undefined. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: The double `||` operator in your code (in `handleSubmit()`) is a copy-paste typo, I guess? Another potential issue could be that you're calling `handleSubmit()` twice with the same button click (the first with `onClick`, the second with `onSubmit`)

Comment: Thanks for the help, @cheesyMan ! THe double operator is a copy-paste typo. About the form, I'll fix that now. The issue is I can't get the form to open and load data because the form isn't getting the row ID properly, so it can't populate the form's fields. I'm not sure how to get that ID to be received by the modal component

Comment: What about `messageContent` variable in your reducer **SET EDIT MESSAGE** action? You're returning it but not extracting in the destructuring assignement.

Comment: Tried changing that, same error :( @cheesyMan